# Blocking calls in Reactive Stream

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I wonder if normal java API calls (I mean methods without I/O) should be threaded as a "mini blocking calls"? Is it acceptable to implement Reactive Streams like this (invoking method before returning Publisher):

```
  public Mono<String> doSomething(Object anyObject){
      validator.validate(anyObject); // it returns void so in this case it cannot be in filter
      return Mono.just(anyObject)
          .flatmap(service::process);
  }
```

instead of (invoking it inside stream)

```
  public Mono<String> doSomething(Object anyObject){
      return Mono.just(anyObject)
          .doOnNext(validator::validate)
          .flatmap(service::process);
  }
```

This validator is only for a example. Does that approach has any disadvantages or these methods before return statement should be always included in a stream?

Comment: if you place it outside the reactor context, the system will not be able to leverage the ability to switch threads as needed to optimize thread usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if normal java API calls (I mean methods without I/O) should be threaded as a "mini blocking calls"?

I'm not quite sure what you mean by mini-blocking calls here - either a method blocks or it doesn't. If it doesn't block because it doesn't need to (the method doesn't involve any IO or other blocking operation) then it's just a standard, synchronous operation.

In this case there's two relevant principles I like to adhere to where possible:

- Keep everything part of the reactive chain (this keeps the code clearer, and means operators that work downstream have the proper effect);
- Avoid the use of `Mono.just()` in all but trivial cases (otherwise you look like you're working with the "promise" of a value rather than one that's immediately available.)

So I'd therefore favour the second approach, since everything there is clearly part of the reactive chain and that makes the code clearer to read IMHO - you're not switching back and forth between reactive and non-reactive looking code.

However, bearing in mind that you'd be using this method as part of a larger reactive chain (most likely via a `flatMap()` call), there's actually another approach I'd prefer if possible - that being to use `transform()` instead, which means you can supply a method which both takes a `Mono` as its parameter, and returns one:

```
public Mono<String> doSomething(Mono<String> mono){
  return mono
      .doOnNext(validator::validate)
      .flatmap(service::process);
}
```

This then keeps everything as part of the reactive chain, and has the additional advantage of avoiding the need to use `Mono.just()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This "mini blocking calls" is really bad name - now I see it. I meant about method which are time consuming, for example let suppose that this previously mentioned method 'validate' needs 5 sec to be processed. Doesn't it provide concurrency issues when it won't be in any Publisher?

Comment: @destro1 Is that 5 seconds just on CPU time? If so then you might want to put it on the `parallel()` scheduler or similar to avoid hogging the event loop for that long - but you could quickly run out of CPU resources either way if you have lots of tasks that are really that intensive!